# Extension of Global Scope Interface

Tags: typescript

I can extend the global scope Window Interface (in file example.d.ts) like this:

```
interface Window {
    locationHelper: LocationHelper;
}
```

This allows me, to call `window.locationHelper` from any .ts file that references example.d.ts. Is it possible to modify the specification in example.d.ts in a way that I am allowed to call `locationHelper` directly, i.e. not as a property from the `window`-object?

Answer (score 4):

You can just declare the variable in the file (`example.d.ts`) :

```
declare var locationHelper : LocationHelper
```

If you look at other members of `window` that are available as global variables, (for example `location`) they are also defined as variables in `lib.d.ts`:

```
declare var location: Location;
```

Comment: Ok, if this is the only solution... Its a little disappointing though, that typescript forces me to do the specification twice.

Comment: @Ferenjito, There is no way I know of not to have to declare it twice. I would expect that if such a method existed, the typescript team would have used it for `lib.d.ts`. Probably a language feature for this is not worth the effort since it has a very narrow usage.